# Inconsistent Math.Floor results

Tags: c#, floor

I'm a bit puzzled by the results of the Math.Floor function in C#.

I get a return of 91 as expected with the call below:

```
Math.Floor(91.0);
```

But if I use the call below I get a returned value of 90, while I still expect 91 in this case.

```
Math.Floor(9.1/0.1);
```

Is this just due to small rounding errors and is there a way to get consistent results?

Comment: That equals `90.999999` (repeating). Floor rounds it down. What is "unexpected"?

Comment: Why would you ask this question without bothering to look an d see what `9.1/0.1` actually produces?

Comment: In the debugger the division shows an answer of 91, not 90.999999. So that's why I find this answer unexpected. My algorithm requires an answer of 91 in this case to work. But if it's the floating accuracy I guess I just need to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this problem is related to precision, since `Math.Floor()` simply doesn't round mathematically and always down instead. So even `90.9999999` still results in only `90`.

For accurate rounding, use `Math.Round()` instead or add `0.5` to the value passed.

Comment: I do want to use floor and not round. But for something that clearly is 91, the answer of 90 surprised me. Guess I'll just have to find a workaround for 91 actually being 90.9999999.

Comment: @ArnoGerretsen This issue most likely isn't exclusive to 91. It may happen with other numbers as well.

Comment: I ended up adding an epsilon value before doing the math, to make sure that I also get the right value when a small precision error would give the wrong value. For my algorithm that worked best.